# Problem with wireless connection in 14.04 lts

Tags: wireless, internet

My problem: I can see and connect to the network, most of the time (sometimes connecting does not work). My main problem is, that even when connection is established, I have no access to the internet. Resetting the router seems to correct the problem for a limited time (until it stops working seemingly arbitrarily). Other devices using the same router have no problem (1 Windows pc, 2 androids). On top of that, when I boot Windows on this very machine, there are no problems either.

I have run the analysis script from:
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

My results are:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9215532/

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried a lot of things since I originally posted this but nothing worked. And then i realized that sometimes, not fixing it can also be a solution.

A solution that works for everyone owning a smartphone is to connect the phone to the local network and use USB tehthering. Works regardless of OS. I know it's stupid. But it just works.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to upgrade the kernel?

kernel.org. has the newes one.

as far as i can remember it was

wget source && unpack and then run ...

```
 make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=-new-wlan kernel-image kernel-headers kernel-source
```

see  this for more information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: Sorry, the article you linked directly says that you shouldn't attempt compiling a kernel when you have no idea what you're doing. And I have to say I have no clue.

Comment: it is not so hard to compile a normal kernel (just do not edit the source)
there is maybe the chance to update or boot the livecd 14.10 (current version) with a newer kernel (just give the livecd a test)

Comment: if the livecd works fine then i think you should update the kernel (newer driver) - or try to get a backported one.

Comment: small search **have not looked** if it is good to download this - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-upgrade-kernel-3-17-ubuntu/ (if you trust the source - check yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this driver parameter that usually works.

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```